# repeating data in ReportViewer

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have assigned a dataTable to report as below, but I am getting only the first row of data in the report, not all of the rows. How can I repeat the results for all rows of the datatable I am assigning?

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Height="1000px" 
                                Width="600px" SizeToReportContent="True">
</rsweb:ReportViewer>


    ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource();
    rd.Name = "DataSet1_DataTable1";
    //rd.Value = ReceiptData;
    rd.Value =(DataTable) ViewState["ReceiptData"];
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("Report/Report.rdlc");
    //ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rd);
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: Show us the source for your report. To display multiple records, you have to use a list control in your rdlc.

Comment: now i have added list on rdlc and then the data on list.

Answer (score 0):

Check what you have in `(DataTable) ViewState["ReceiptData"];`. It may be that the viewstyate has only 1 record in it.

Comment: multiple records are present in viewstate. that i saw by debugging.

Comment: check the comment made by @nunespascal on your question

Comment: now it not displying me even single record. How i need to give group expression. i am not able to add my rdlc source here as it is too big.  the error is "The table ‘table1’ is in a list that has no group expressions defined for it. To use a data region in a list, the list must have group expressions."

Comment: You need to assign the data source to RDLC at design time and then assign DataTable columns to RDLC list columns